# Is there a (simple) way to modify the syntax of some particular programming language?

Tags: syntax, programming-languages

This question might be naïve, so please feel free to press me for clarification. I am coming to computer science from a math background, so people keep telling me that functional programming languages like Haskell will feel very natural for me, but I find the syntax of a lot of languages (not just functional languages) very ugly and unintuitive.

In Haskell, for a small example, type declarations are written with `::`, e.g.,

```
str :: String 
str = "Hello, World!"
```

Is there any way for me to modify the syntax in my own system so that the function of `::` could be performed by something else, like `:::`, or maybe `;;`, or better yet `:is_a:`, so that I could perform the same function as above with:

```
str ::: String 
str = "Hello, World!"
```

To be clear, I am not worried about any pragmatic concerns regarding the difficulty in sharing code if I modify the syntax in my system; I am solely wondering if in theory it is possible to modify the fundamental syntax of a programming language, and if so, how.

Please feel free to revise the tags, or ask for clarification.

Comment: `sed s/:::/::/` would probably get you 99% of the way there. The last 1% is a lot harder, but certainly it's doable or else how would any programming language get implemented in the first place...? But, like, I strongly recommend that you do not do this. It's a lot easier than you may think at first to get used to a surface syntax. Hell, you do it all the time in mathematics, there's always a first section that goes "for the purposes of this paper, I'll use the following notations: ...", and then you just have to suffer through whatever choices the author made for the rest of the paper.

Comment: @DanielWagner Super helpful comment, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A really broad subject, and you might get more detailed answers in the software engineering and computer science forums of Stack Exchange. But I will try to give a few pointers.

Obviously I don't know how far you have come from math into programming stuff, so please bear with me if parts of this answer are just obvious to you.

If you set aside the need of swapping source code between programmers (a really big **if** in practice), you may define any programming language syntax you want, ... provided your syntax definitions are *consistent*. The trouble is, ensuring language consistency is not simple at all.

That means: you must be able to somehow produce an executable *parser* program that can read the source code written using your nice new syntax, and produce a *syntax tree*. Machine code generation and/or direct interpreted execution start from the syntax tree.

This being the 21st century, you have software tools such as [Yacc/Bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) and [Lex/Flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)) that will write the actual parser code for you, starting from some high-level description of your grammar provided by **you**, typically in something close to Backus-Naur form (BNF).

The parser is essentially a stack-based automaton. Now, if there is *any* chance of your new grammar being ambiguous somewhere, your parser generator tool will not produce a compilable description of a stack-based automaton. Instead, it will output some partially unclear error message, such as [shift-reduce conflict at line 413](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Shift_002fReduce.html) . From my limited experience looking at working language designers, they spend a lot of their time fighting shift-reduce conflicts in their grammars.

For example, you say you might want to assign some semantic value to “;;”. But Haskell, like many other programming languages, assigns an established value to a single semicolon. It is an instruction terminator. How to ensure we avoid any and all ambiguity at that level ? By getting the BNF thru the parser generation tool. That's the only way.

More details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators). The best way to understand the problem in some depth is to create a parser for some mini-language. You can use either the classic Bison/Flex toolkit, which was produced in the realm of traditional imperative languages. Or you can use one of the Haskell specific tools, such as for example [Megaparsec](https://markkarpov.com/tutorial/megaparsec.html).

That being said, part of the ugliness you seem to be perceiving was probably caused by the historical necessity to use only ASCII characters, as in the old days this was a requirement for source code exchange. To write a *not equal to*, Fortran used .NE. as there was no Unicode and hence no '≠' character. The designers of the C language, faced with the same problem circa 1975 AD, preferred to use “!=”.

Haskell, at the vanguard in 2020 AD, still uses by default a single ordinary ASCII dot '.' for function composition, rather than the appropriate '∘' character used in mathematical texts. It will probably take a long time to get that fixed.

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely possible to redefine the syntax of a programming language. What you are doing in such case is inventing a new programming language which has the same features as the original one, but a different syntax for the language constructs.

It is not a very simple thing to do, but here are two possible approaches:

## Pre-processor / Translator

You could write a program that reads a file in the new syntax, parses it, and translates it into a file with the original language. At that point the original compiler / interpreter can be used.

The main advantage of this approach is that you only need to provide a translation. Everything else can be reused.

The main disadvantage is that you will still have most error messages (e.g. type errors) pointing to the translation, and mentioning the syntax of the original language. You might be able to translate them back, but that depends on how different the syntax is.

## Fork the language implementation

Nothing prevents you to download the GHC source code (or GCC, or ...) and modify its parser and pretty printer to use the new syntax. You'll have to find the right spot to modify among a huge number of files, but it could be done.

The main disadvantage here is that you'll have to re-merge your changes whenever a new version of GHC is released, or stick to an older version.

## Conclusion

Having a nice syntax is nice, but not that important. Researchers in PL theory nowadays never discuss syntactic issues, but only semantic ones: new features, new types, new optimizations, and so on.

Feel free to modify the syntax of any language, if you so wish. It can be a fun project -- a way to challenge oneself to understand a large code base just enough to make a little change here and there. Keep however in mind that other people, most likely, will not want to read code written in your own syntax: there are already so many languages around, and learning a new syntax for an already known language can be seen as a waste of effort, which could be spent in learning something really new.